# Please use the review queues

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Currently the review queue for the close votes is getting quite long (see below), while we moderators help out with closing clear cut cases, some questions may benefit for a more diligent approach.

Please use your privileges to not let it get out of hand.

While you're here, [click here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/review/close/117134) and do a few. Thank you very much.

[image: Current close review queue]

Please don't forget to *periodically* check the review queues if you would like to help with the quality of the site.
There is a dedicated button in the top right corner depicted as a list with a check mark:

[image: Screenshot of the interface for accessing reviews]

Comment: Yeah, I notice about 50 VTC questions each day, but it's beyond my privileges for now 

Comment: The students are asking questions about take-home exams while the instructors are busy grading...

Comment: @WilliamR.Ebenezer In any case, you can only perform I think 20 close vote reviews a day, even at max privilege.

Comment: @Jan I see. I didn't know that. Don't close votes per day increase as you keep reviewing? (somewhat like flags)

Comment: @WilliamR.Ebenezer No, close votes stay the same all the time. Only flags increase, as far as I know.