# Disagree that these questions should have been closed

Tags: discussion

1. [How does steam prevent oxidation in tea leaves?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/143303/how-does-steam-prevent-oxidation-in-tea-leaves/143308#143308)

This was closed for lack of clarity.  It seemed perfectly clear to me.  I couldn't have answered it otherwise.   Perhaps those not familiar with tea processing had trouble understanding it.  But that doesn't, by itself, mean it's unclear.  For instance, those not familiar with thermodynamics might have trouble understanding a question about that subject, irrespective of its clarity.

2. [Food-grade antifungal preservatives for alcohol-containing aqueous non-food product that won't UV-yellow when dried?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/144999/food-grade-antifungal-preservatives-for-alcohol-containing-aqueous-non-food-prod)

This was my own question.  It was closed as a "personal medical question".  It is (obviously, I think) not a personal medical question.  Where in the question is there a solicitation for advice on medical treatment?  I asked if anyone knew of compounds within a certain class (food-grade and/or not on the California Prop 65 list) that (A) would have antimicrobial activity in a certain type of product, and (B) also not yellow when exposed to UV.  "A" is a biochemistry question, and "B" is a chemistry question.

---

A general comment:  Posting here seems to be the only practical mechanism for getting closed questions reopened.  I've tried the built-in mechanism, voting to reopen, and nothing more happens.  It just sits there with my one vote to reopen.

Is there a "reopen" queue that people review? Even if there were, I suspect it would be the same people that voted to close, so that's not going to change anything, particularly since, when you vote to reopen, you can't explain *why* you voted to reopen.  It's only here that you can explain why.

Comment: The system is a bit biased towards closing. There is a reopen queue, but I surmise that a fair amount of voting happens on the front page. I'm not sure, but just bumping the question to the front page, maybe plus dropping a comment, might help?

Answer (score 11):

I completely agree with your reasoning and personally I wouldn't think of closing any of the aforementioned questions.
In my opinion, it would be fair to mod-reopen both questions within the next 24 hours unless a review queue gets processed or a close-voter provides an objective reason against it.

As for the reopen queue, there is still not that many users willing to take part in reviewing despite a [fairly recent reminder](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4691/please-use-the-review-queues).
Since moderators cannot vote "normally" ([a mod vote is binding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41062/add-a-way-for-moderators-to-cast-a-normal-non-binding-close-open-vote)), it would be really nice if the community members were a bit more active in reviewing.

P.S. I have mod-re-opened both questions since this answer has been well-received and there were no counterarguments after one day.